# Jmeter - Subract a year from the current date

Tags: jmeter

I wanted to subtract 1 year from the current date.
Ex: current date = 12/1/2017, I want to get 11/01/2016.

If I just subtract 1 from each date object(year, month, and date), it has been taken as just numbers.

Is there any function or direct way to subtract a year?

Answer (score 1):

In JMeter 3.3 there is a new function called [__timeShift](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__timeShift) that you can use:

> ${__timeShift(dd/MM/yyyy,12/01/2017,P-365D,,)}